# Sorting a multidimensional array, lowest to highest, only the first element remains unsorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've been playing around with this problem, trying to sort out this multidimensional array but I keep on getting the wrong output. The array is sorted, except for the first element. Everything is in order, apart from the first element in the array. The first element in the sorted array, is also the first element in the array before it's sorted, which is sNamesLongitude[0][0] .

The string `sNamesLongitude[2][306]` array has two rows. The first row holds the names of stations of the London underground, the second row holds its corresponding longitude. I'm trying to sort out the array so the stations with the lowest value for its longitude comes first in the array, and the last value will have the highest value for its longitude, while keeping their corresponding name (row 1), together with its longitude.

```
String[][] temp = new String[2][1];
    for (int a = 0; a < sNamesLongitude[0].length - 1; a++) {

        if ((Double.parseDouble(sNamesLongitude[1][a])) > (Double.parseDouble(sNamesLongitude[1][a + 1]))) {

            temp[0][0] = sNamesLongitude[0][a];
            temp[1][0] = sNamesLongitude[1][a];

            sNamesLongitude[0][a] = sNamesLongitude[0][a + 1];
            sNamesLongitude[1][a] = sNamesLongitude[1][a + 1];

            sNamesLongitude[0][a + 1] = temp[0][0];
            sNamesLongitude[1][a + 1] = temp[1][0];
            a=0;
        }
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the exception ?

Comment: I've updated the code, there's no exception any more. The array is now sorted except for the first element which has a higher value than some of the following values. This element is also first in the pre-sorted array.

Comment: in your for loop I think the condition should be (a < sNamesLongitude[0].length);

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it gives an outofbounds exception because a+1 is used in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `temp` only has two elements `temp[0][0]` and `temp[1][0]`

your code -

```
sNamesLongitude[0][a + 1] = temp[0][a]; // Gets exception
```

`a` might go up to values greater than `1` (to 306, as per your question), hence the exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've just looked at my code again and found that out, silly me. However, the array still isn't being sorted.

Comment: Mark this is as the answer if this helped.

Comment: I appreciate your help Ankit Rustagi, it did solve a bug, but the main issue, the multidimensional array still isn't completely sorted, (the first element is still in the wrong place) still isn't solved yet. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

After spending a whole day on it, the answer is:
`a` should = -1, and not 0 at the end of the `if block`.

Can anyone please explain why though, is it something to do with scope?

Comment: Just found out, its because the for loop increments it by 1. Hope it helps someone with a similar problem. If it does, please mark this answer as useful